# WPF String Format numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I seem to be missing something very simple. I have a textbox in a WPF app. The user enters a numeric value into this box, ie 35600. I want the textbox to display this number as 35,600. I have tried numerous stringformat combinations but nothing happens with any of them? Below is the latest example.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding MyString, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}" >
```

Comment: Try `StringFormat={}{0:N0}`.

Comment: It's not a string - it's a number. Formatting a string with a format of N0 isn't appropriate; you'll need to parse the value to a number and then reformat *that* with N0.

Comment: oh I feel stupid now. The property I was binding to was a string not numeric! Thanks for the answer though.